# javascript, let function if not defined

Tags: javascript

Every time a modal is opened I load via ajax some html + js, like this:

```
var loadModalJs = function() {
   ...
}

$(function() { loadModalJs(); });
```

It works with `var`, but if I replace `var` with `let`, when the modal is closed and then opened again I get `Identifier 'loadTabJs' has already been declared`

I tried something like this, without success:

```
if(typeof loadModalJs === 'undefined') {
    let loadModalJs = function() {
       ...
    };  
}
loadModalJs(); // ReferenceError: loadModalJs is not defined
```

I don't like using var because my IDE complains about "'var' used instead of 'let' or 'const'"... But none of them seems to work... How could I do?

Comment: Apparently, you're re-declaring `let loadModalJs`, hence the error. You probably want to only declare it once or at the very least just re-assign it. It's hard to see where the re-declaration is happening because it's not included in this code.

Comment: @VLAZ the redeclaration happens then this code is run a second time, how can I declare it only if it's not declared?

Comment: If the function does not change and should not be redefined, use const to find where you are trying to redefine it

Comment: @SofiaGrillo *how* is the code run a second time? Why does `loadModalJs` need to be declared again? Maybe it's as simple as making a single function that takes a parameter and calling it with a given value, instead of making a new function every time.

Comment: 1) use `window.function` if it *realy* need to be a global function (bad idea, keep the global scope as clean as possible), 2) `let` is block-scope spectifi. if you declare a function/variable inside a block (`{...}`) its only available in this specific block/scope.

Answer (score 4):

The error you placed into the comment is correct: at no point do you define the variable *in scope* -- you define it within the the `if` clause, and it is not available outside of that clause, your reference to it in the `if` statement is to an undefined global variable.

Also, if your variable is only ever going to be `undefined` or a `function`, then no need to test its type, as `undefined` evaluates to false.

```
let loadModalJs;

// ...your other code here...


// This bit within the function/scope run multiple times:
if (!loadModalJs) {
    loadModalJs = function() {
       ...
    };  
}

if (loadModalJs) { 
  loadModalJs(); 
}
```

Comment: The fact is that the whole block can run multiple times, in this case it'd gave error on line 1 the second time, because it's already declared.

Comment: I think I got it, the `if` constructor is considered a scope in javascript, contrary to other languages... I could define it globally with `window.`

Comment: @SofiaGrillo: Yes...in JavaScript, anything withing `{}` curly braces is a scope. So define the var is I did, at the top of your outer-most scope. No need to touch the `window` object.

Answer (score 2):

### In addition to the current answer:

Your second snippet could work if you use `var` instead of `let`.

As `if` creates its own block `{}`:

- `let` is limited to the immediate block `{}`.
- `var` is limited to the immediate function block `{}` (or global if there are no functions).

E.g.:

```js
if (true) {
  var x = "It'll work outside the if.";
}

console.log(x);
```

---

### Edit:

As an additional tip, you might be careful with the way you 'create' functions in javascript:

- Functions **defined**, e.g. `let myFunction = function() { }`, are under *top-to-bottom* flow of control (i.e. first define, then use).
- Functions **declared**, e.g. `function myFunction() { }`, are *hoisted* (i.e. declare and use where you want, in the same scope).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lee Goddard's answer. You may consider learning about the difference between `let` and `var`. The most key difference is:

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement or expression on which it is used, unlike the var keyword, which declares a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. - [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good opportunity to use guard/default clauses:

```js
let f = function(){
  console.log('f is defined');
}

let g;
g = f || function() {
    console.log('f was NOT defined');
}
g();
f = null;
g = f || function() {
  console.log('f was NOT defined');
}
g();
```

with a twist:

```js
let f, g;



for (let i=0; i<8; i++){
  g = f || function() {
    console.log('f was NOT defined');
  }
  g();
  f = (f)?undefined:function(){console.log('f is defined');};
}
```

So in your case this would be:

```
let guardedModal = loadModalJs || function() {
        // your code here
}
guardedModal();
```

Comment: All these involve putting `let loadModalJs` in the parent page which is what I wanted to avoid... but as I see there are no alternatives

Comment: I want to do `let something` only if that something is not already let...

Comment: ... because if a single-page panel can run thousands of different actions, I'll need to declare thousands of variables

Comment: @SofiaGrillo if you give us the reason why you need to redeclare `loadModuleJs` then we could probably give you a better alternative than redeclaring it. Right now, it's very very hard to give a generic solution to an unknown problem.